# AdadeltaOptimizer Example code

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Does anyone have an example for code that uses tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer with good results?

I have a TF graph, that was originally set with tf.train.AdamOptimizer, and is working well. When I replace it with AdadeltaOptimizer, with the default params, it gives lousy results.

I used Cuda 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

The below is example code which works with 'AdadeltaOptimizer' optimizer. It works with 'Adam'. The only difference between them that Adam is insensitive to "learning rate" and 'Adadelta' is sensitive. 
I advice you to read more about optimization algorithm (like [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-differences-between-update-rules-like-AdaDelta-RMSProp-AdaGrad-and-AdaM)).
In your own example, just try to change 'learning rate' to be smaller or bigger (it is named 'hyperparameter optimization').

Note: 
From my experience, 'Adam' is a very good optimizer for RNN, better than 'AdaDelta' (using example code, 'Adam' achieve better score much faster). On the other hand, for CNN, SGD+Momentum works best.

Code, which learn MNIST classification using Bi-LSTM:

```
# Mnist classification using Bi-LSTM
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import numpy as np

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
learning_rate   = 0.01
training_epochs = 100
batch_size  = 64
seq_length  = 28
heigh_image = 28
hidden_size = 128
class_numer = 10
input   = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, heigh_image])
target  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, class_numer])
seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

def fulconn_layer(input_data, output_dim, activation_func=None):
    input_dim = int(input_data.get_shape()[1])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim, output_dim]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_dim]))
    if activation_func:
        return activation_func(tf.matmul(input_data, W) + b)
    else:
        return tf.matmul(input_data, W) + b       

with tf.name_scope("BiLSTM"):
  with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
    lstm_fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
  with tf.variable_scope('backward'):
    lstm_bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
  outputs, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=lstm_fw_cell, cell_bw=lstm_bw_cell, inputs=input,sequence_length=seq_len, dtype=tf.float32, scope="BiLSTM")  

# As we have Bi-LSTM, we have two output, which are not connected. So merge them
outputs = tf.concat(2, outputs)
# As we want do classification, we only need the last output from LSTM.
last_output = outputs[:,0,:]
# Create the final classification layer
yhat = fulconn_layer(last_output, class_numer)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(yhat, target))
optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost) # AdamOptimizer
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(target, 1), tf.argmax(yhat, 1)), tf.float32))
gpu_opts = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3)
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_opts)) as session:
  session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  print ("Start Learing")
  for epoch in range(training_epochs):
      for i in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
          x_batch, y_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
          x_batch = x_batch.reshape([batch_size, seq_length, heigh_image])
          train_seq_len = np.ones(batch_size) * seq_length
          session.run([optimizer], feed_dict={input: x_batch, target: y_batch, seq_len: train_seq_len})

      train_accuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={input: x_batch, target: y_batch, seq_len: train_seq_len})
      x_test = mnist.test.images.reshape([-1, seq_length, heigh_image])
      y_test = mnist.test.labels
      test_seq_len = np.ones(x_test.shape[0]) * seq_length
      test_accuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={input: x_test, target: y_test, seq_len: test_seq_len})
      print("epoch: %d, train_accuracy: %3f, test_accuracy: %3f" % (epoch, train_accuracy, test_accuracy))
```